# how to make the keyboard invisible on start of some Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

When on of my Fragment is start - i want to make the keybaord go away !

I try this ( not work .. )

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_behavior, container, false);


    //
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);

    }
```

I also try to define

```
      <activity android:name="com.your.package.ActivityName"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"  />
```

But also not work

Please ... any help :(

Thanks

Comment: How are you adding Fragment to Activity? I mean in ViewPager, FrameLayout via fragment Transaction, from XML And can you post the xml of Your Fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code inside **onCreateView()**

```
try {

   InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

   input.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

}catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: not working .. keyboard still up when focus this fragment

Comment: try to rebuild your project and check because this code work on my machine and also you don't need to define fragment in manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: not working .. keyboard still up when focus this fragment

Answer (score 1):

```
/***Just try the below code Snipet***/

Inside your onCreateView of Fragment

 getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

And put the below piece of code inside your Main Fragment activity tag in manifest file

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

Comment: When the keybaord is hidden - on my ui i will see that some of the button is bigger - now this button is bigger but the keybaord is shown still